# onclick error ".forEach is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am fairly new to javascript and am trying to load a JSON from data.js file when a button is clicked. the JSON is stored as variable `large_traits`.
I am sure I have other changes I need to make for this to properly append to the html file, but the issue I am trying to currently figure out is the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: large_traits[0].forEach is not a function

My HTML is as follows:  `<button onclick="loadChar()">Submit</button>`.

And here is my javascript function:

```js
function loadChar() {

    large_traits[0].forEach((trait, traitDict) => {
        charList = d3.select("characteristics")
        charList.append("li")
            .classed("char-columns", true)
        inputTag = charList.append("input")
            .attr("type", "checkbox")
            .attr("id", traitDict.id)
            .attr("name", traitDict.name)
            .attr("value", traitDict.value)
        inputTag.append("label")
            .attr("for", traitDict.name)
            .text(traitDict.name)
    })}
```

I am trying to load each JSON object into an `li` with a checkbox for user input.

when I console.log the variable large_traits, it returns this in the console:
`0: active: {id: "active", name: "active", value: "active", size: "large"} adaptable: {id: "adaptable", name: "adaptable", value: "adaptable", size: "large"} affectionate: {id: "affectionate", name: "affectionate", value: "affectionate", size: "large"} agile: {id: "agile", name: "agile", value: "agile", size: "large"} alert: {id: "alert", name: "alert", value: "alert", size: "large"} aloof: {id: "aloof", name: "aloof", value: "aloof", size: "large"}`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What ` large_traits` is supposed to be ?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what's in this file, but it probably should be `large_traits.forEach`...

Comment: could you please console.log(large_traits) and add result to the question description?

Comment: well is `large_traits[0]`  an array ? if not, you cannot use foreach method

Comment: large_traits is stored in my data.js file. here is the first object `const large_traits = [{
    "loyal": {
      "id": "loyal",
      "name": "loyal",
      "value": "loyal",
      "size": "large"
    },`

Comment: So large_traits[0] is an object. Not an array. you cannot use forEach on an object. use `Object.entries(large_traits[0).forEach` or Object.values or Object.keys. Depending on what you want to loop over

Comment: **N.B.** `JSON` is not an object. `JSON` is _always_ a string.

Comment: Ok, great. I added object.entries, and it no longer returned the error. nothing is logged, and nothing was appended. Do I need to include an innerHTML statement for it to append?

Comment: `large_traits[0]` is a single element and it's not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is just that you are accessing the first element of the array instead of the array itself. Try:

```
function loadChar() {
  large_traits.forEach((trait, traitDict) => {
    charList = d3.select("characteristics")
    charList.append("li")
      .classed("char-columns", true)
    inputTag = charList.append("input")
      .attr("type", "checkbox")
      .attr("id", traitDict.id)
      .attr("name", traitDict.name)
      .attr("value", traitDict.value)
    inputTag.append("label")
      .attr("for", traitDict.name)
      .text(traitDict.name)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with your console.log, it seems that your `large_traits[0]` is an object

so try:

```
Object.entries(large_traits[0]).forEach(([trait,traitDict]) =>
```